# how can I validate the language of an xcode app?

Tags: xcode

How can I validate the language of an Xcode app?  I checked the project-level properties but I didn't see a reference to the project language (ObjectiveC, Swift, etc).  I checked Info.plist as well and did not see it specified there either.

Comment: There is not a single flag in a project that specifies language.  What are you trying to accomplish, to ensure that all files are a specific language?

Comment: You can easily have mixed projects with both Swift and Objective C as well.

Comment: What is an "Xcode app"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

When you create your project, you should see an option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pena.  So based on the screenshot in your post would all new files get added to the project as Swift files by default?  Since an Xcode project can support files written in different languages, how would files get added in different languages?  Is there a language selection dropdown as part of new file creation or does each file have some type of properties/attributes pane where the language for the file can be changed?  Or does the Xcode compiler infer the language of each file based on the syntax of the file contents?

Comment: @JimThompson If I were to create this project, then yes, all my files would be created in swift. However there are plenty of helpful links on the web if you need to put objective c or some other language code in your swift project.

Comment: @EricD By default they are in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

> I didn't see a reference to the project language

Because there is no such thing as "project language". Individual files in a single project may be in Objective-C, Objective-C++, C++, Assembler, AppleScript, Swift, and possibly other languages.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Whatever. I'm just glad I'm not writing in it any more...

Comment: @NicolasMiari What's wrong with "Assembler"?

Comment: I was under the impression that _Assembly_ is the name of the programming language(s), and _Assembler_ is the name of the software tool that turns source code in said language into machine instructions. It is a moot point indeed, and the misnomer seems to be so widely spread that perhaps we could call it "accepted variation".